# Javascript countdown timer not starting at all

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>    
<head>    
    <title>Countdown Timer</title>    
</head>
<body>
 <label for="timer"><abbr title="Countdown">Cdown</abbr></label>    
 <input id="timer" value=""/>   
 <button id="timer" onclick="countdown(-1)">Start </button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Javascript-

```
   function countdown(val){    
   var number =document.getElementById("timer").value;    
   var interval = setInterval(function()    
 {


    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML =parseInt(number,10)+val;    

    if (number== 0)    
    clearInterval(interval);

}, 1000);
```

The countdown timer does not start at all. Could anyone help me figure out why my code isn't working?

Comment: Using Same Id For input type And Button  id="timer" Id should be Unique

Comment: In example code javascript is missing a } is this also on our code?

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are using same id for your button and input tag :)Change your button id to some other name.

Answer (score 0):

You shold Give Default Value to input Field Otherwise It Will Get `NaN(Not a Number)` HopeFully  It Will Work Great For You 
 Also Id Is unique do not duplicate with other elements Also InnerHtml Does Not Give You Value for value you have to use .value

```
 <html>    
    <head>    
        <title>Countdown Timer</title>    
    </head>
    <body>
     <label for="timer"><abbr title="Countdown">Cdown</abbr></label>    
     <input id="timer" value="20"/>   
     <button id="buttontimer" onclick="countdown(-1)">Start </button>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </html>
```

Javascript-

```
  function countdown(val){  
   var number =document.getElementById("timer").value;    
   //setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
   var interval = setInterval(function()    
 {

    number = parseInt(number)+val;
    document.getElementById("timer").value =     number;

    if (number == 0)    
    clearInterval(interval);

}, 1000);
}
```

Id Should Be Unique it thought that id is of button not input Use different Id For button

Comment: Thanks a lot @Junaid Ahmed. So then how exactly do i enter the time dynamically since i have to give a default value to input element. Is there a different method to do this?

Comment: @KevinGeorge You can use one input box for take input of time how much time this should have by using this input box

Comment: You can also add start stop button for this counter